# TFS2012 build server for both SharePoint 2010 and 2013

Tags: 2010, 2013, administration, tfs, build-server

Is there a way to use just one machine to configure a build server for both SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013? I'd like to know if anyone succeeded in such a task. We want to use PowerShell remoting for deployment.

So far I have found [a guide on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff622991.aspx) that goes in depth about configuring a build server for SP2013, but no mention of using it for both 2010 and 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TFS build server doesn't necessarily have to have SharePoint truly installed.  You just need to ensure the assemblies for each version of SharePoint are available during the build process.   You can have two versions of the same assemblies in the GAC. In addition, I would simply copy the 14 HIVE from a 2010 server and the 15 HIVE from a 2013 server to the appropriate location on the build server.

Comment: On a side note, I would ensure all of your references to the SharePoint assemblies are configured to use the specific version (you set this in the properties of the reference in Visual Studio).  This way, if you have 14 and 15 assemblies in the GAC, there is no confusion for msbuild as to which one to use.